# C++ stoi out of scope issue

Tags: c++, string, scope

I am using the latest version of C++ and I am trying to run the following code. However, its keeps telling me that stoi is "not declared in this scope". I am new to C++ so please share if you have any ideas.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int a;
for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
{
    string str(argv[1]);

    a=stoi(str);


   if (a<1) {
       cout<< "the sequence length must be greater than 1"<<endl;
   } else {
       cout <<"consecutive "<< a<<endl; // prints the input number of required consecutive
   }
}

int num[1000000];
int n, j;
n=1;

for (int x=1;!cin.eof() ; ++x)
{
    cin>>num[x];

    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cout<< "error, only integers allowed"<<endl;
    break;
    }


    else if (x>=a)

    {
        while ( num[x-n+1] - num[x-n] == 1)

        { ++n;

        if (n == a)
        { cout<< "sequence found: " ;

        for (j=a-1; j >=0; --j)

            cout<< num[x-j]<<" ";
        break;
        }
        }
    }
}

cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which compiler and how you compile (e.g., command)?

Comment: I've tried to run this code: https://ideone.com/AJcMA0 but it gives different error. Are you sure this is the error you get?

Comment: I am using eclipse and just building the built-in build tool @101010

Comment: any reason you are using `stoi()` instead of `atoi()`?

Comment: If you are using g++/clang you need to use `-std=c++11`

Comment: Compiles fine on MSVC. You probably don't have `the latest version of C++`. `std::stoi` was added to C++11.

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion is your version of Eclipse supporting C++11?

Comment: 'stoi' was not declared in this scope" is the error @piotrsmaron

Comment: I realized that could be the issue but I have C++11 @JameyD

Comment: I tried atoi() as well but same out of scope error @PhotometricStereo

Comment: *You* are using C++11, but your compiler does not, it seems.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309095/stdstoi-not-recognized-by-eclipse

Comment: btw, one does not "have" C++11. That's like saying "I have English".

Comment: Solved! Thank you all

Comment: @PhotometricStereo: Hopefully because `atoi` is broken by design and `std::stoi` isn't.

Comment: regarding `for (int x=1;!cin.eof() ; ++x)`, don't trust the `!cin.eof()`. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::stoi` is `C++11` and above feature, Hence enable C++11 on your compilation.

In gcc or clang, the flag is `-std=c++11`

```
CXX -std=c++11 cc.cc
```

where CXX will be either `g++` or `clang++`.

Please make this change also, in header inclusion part

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Better yet, remove `using namespace std;` entirely.

Comment: Agreed, saves some extra typing in the current example :)

Comment: C++11 or newer is default from GCC 5 IIRC (certainly trunk) so you're not on the "latest C++" :)

Comment: It is tricky on Windows to get GCC > 4.8. Most searches will take you to mingw.